# Roll a die until the sum of the rolls is prime. Repeat this again and again. Show that the expected value of the number of rolls is $>2.428$

Tags: probability, statistics, prime-numbers

So, let's denote the number of throws with $X$.
For example, if the first roll is a $2$,then $X=1$.
If the first roll is a $1$ and the second roll is a $6$, then $X=2$.
If the first one is $4$,the second is $2$ and the third $5$, then $X=3$, etc.

Show that the expected value of $X$ is at least $2.428$.

// Edit:
I have first tried to prove it by writing a program that simulates all possible outcome, but even after numerous changes and optimization, it does not run under reasonable time (I am not even sure it would reach $2.428$ under $20$ minutes, and the ideal runtime would be under a minute).
I have no idea what other way I can approach the problem, I have tried to represent the possibilities as a tree, but I haven't figured out any pattern in it yet.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is the source of the $~2.428~$ number, with respect to this problem. 
 For example, were you assigned a problem that specifically asked you to prove that the expected number of rolls was $~> 2.428~?$  As near as I can determine, the pertinent rational number that slightly exceeds $~2.428~$ is $~\dfrac{17}{7},~$ and I don't see the significance of that fraction, with respect to this problem.

Comment: You need to go 30 layers in the tree.  Seems like the true value is just a hair below 2.4285.

Comment: How large of a lower bound on $\mathbb{E}[X]$ were you able to compute?  Using a spreadsheet, I was able to account through roll 20 before the numbers started getting large enough I was concerned about roundoff errors, but this gave me an lower bound of $2.4241$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring who are you asking?  I used a computer algebra system that can handle the exact rational values much further than level 20.  The estimate one gets from level 30 is about 2.42809.  At layer 128 I have a lower bound of 2.428791369... and doing another 128 layers doesn't budge those digits.

Comment: @JBL I was asking OP, since they had mentioned it didn't run in a "reasonable time" without mentioning what estimate they did get.  Specifically, I'm a little concerned that the implementation OP is using doesn't even consider lower bounds for the tail's input on the expected value, since we don't see the mathematics behind their implementation.

Comment: @JBL Confirming that all (though I didn't bother to use any rational arithmetic and just wrote a trivial Asymptote program that ran in under a second). The only clean bound I could get by hand in a one line computation is $7/3$.  Looks like it is a "computational methods" homework, indeed, rather than a neat math. problem...

Comment: @fedja Can you review my solution? I'm guessing it's a powered up version of your "one line computation is 7/3".

Comment: @JBL Do you mind elaborating on your "estimate from level 30"? I'm wondering if it's similar to what I did.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.07698

Comment: @CalvinLin I have used precisely the procedure in Section 3 of the link shared by user51547.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n$ represent the expected number of rolls to reach a prime if we start with a sum of $n$.
We're asked to show that $a_0 \geq 2.428$.

Show the following numbered statements (If you're stuck, explain what you've tried):

1. $a_p = 0 $ for $ p $ prime.
2. For $c$ not prime (so allowing for $c=0, 1$), $a_c = 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( a _{c+1} + a_{c+2} + a_{c+3} + a_{c+4} + a_{c+5} + a_{c+6} ) $.
3. For $c$ composite, $a_c \geq 3$.

   - The idea here is that in each subsequent roll, we stop at most $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time, hence the expected number of rolls is at least 3.

Using this naive estimate, since $ a_4 \geq 3, a_6 \geq 3$, hence

- $a_1 \geq 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( 0 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 3 + 0 ) = 2 $
- $ a_0 \geq 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( 2 + 0 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 3 ) = \frac{7}{3} = 2.33$.

How can we strengthen this? Let's revisit the $ a_c \geq 3$ bound.

- The $a_c \geq 3$ occurs when exactly 2 of $c+1$ through $c+6$ are prime (meaning that those values of the form $6k+1, 6k+5$ are prime), and we have $ a_c \geq 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( 0  + 0 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 ) = 3$. If that's all that we have, there is no hope of increasing $a_n$ further.
- For composite $c$ where only 1 of $c+1$ through $c+6$ is prime, then $a_c \geq 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( 0 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 ) = 3.5$. The first occurrence is $ c= 21$.
- For composite $c$ where $c+1$ through $c+6$ are all composite, then $a_c \geq 1 + \frac{1}{6}(3+3+3+3+3+3) = 4$. The first occurrence is $ c = 90$.

With these slightly puffed up values, we might be able to backtrack to increase the estimates for small values of $c$.
In particular, show that
4. If  $a_1+a_4+a_6 \geq 2+3+3+0.57$, then $a_0 \geq 2.428$.

- This follows from using $a_0 = 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6)$.
- This suggests how much more we need to push the values up.

5. If $a_4 + a_6 \geq 6.487$, then $a_0 \geq 2.428$.

   - This follows from substituting $a_1 = 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7)$ into the formula for $a_0$.
   - This suggests how we can get the desired result by considering $a_{c+1} + a_{c+2} + a_{c+3} + a_{c+4} + a_{c+5} + a_{c+6}$ for larger values of $c$.

> **Claim** (Not showing calculations): If you calculate backwards using
>
> - $b_{100} = 3, b_{99} = 3, b_{98} = 3, b_{97} = 0 , b_{96} = 3, b_{95} = 3$,
> - $b_p = 0 $ for prime $p$
> - $b_c = 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( b_{c+1} + b_{c+2} + b_{c+3} + b_{c+4} + b_{c+5} + b_{c+6})$ for composite $c $ between 0 and 94,
>
> Then $b_0 \geq 2.428$.

**Corollary:** Clearly $a_n \geq b_n$. Hence $a_0 \geq 2.428$.

Notes

- The first few calculated values are $b_{94} = \frac{7}{2}$, $b_{93} = \frac{43}{12}, b_{92} = \frac{265}{72}, \ldots$
- There could be minor rounding errors in my calculation. If so, you might need to push the calculation out further.
- The last few calculated values are $b_6 = 3.262, b_4 = 3.226, b_1 = 2.081$. These together give $b_0 = 1 + \frac{1}{6} ( 2.081 + 0 + 0 + 3.226 + 0 + 3.262) \geq 2.428 $.  (Yes ideally i should provide one more significant digit to ensure $b_0 \geq 2.428$.)
- I just so happened to test with the first 100 numbers, and ended up with $b_0 = 2.428$. (I started testing with first 10/20/50/100.)
- I do not know what $a_0$ is. I'd be interested in finding an upper bound for it.

Comment: "If you calculate backwards using..." Of course, you are absolutely right, but this is more or less equivalent to JBL's 30 layers (i.e., going up to 120) and I would certainly hate doing it by hand :-)

Comment: @fedja Ah, if you're confident that's what JBL did, that's great. I asked JBL for further details.$\quad$  From my interpretation of what OP did and Brian's "account through roll 20", their approach is different.

Comment: JBL might also compute the table of probabilities to reach $n$ after $m$ steps, which is technically a bit more hustle than handling the expectations directly as you did. What I'm saying is just that no "pen and paper" solution is in sight. I'm also puzzled about what program the OP could possibly write here that would run for over 20 minutes and yeah, Brian's approach should be different as well. I agree here.

Comment: @fedja That's basically what I did (the table of probabilities).  Obviously that's keeping track of a lot more details than I needed, especially when compared to Calvin Lin's solution here.  As a meaningless benefit, I can tell you with certainty that there are $333168612385$ sequences $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{20}$ such that $1\leq a_i \leq 6$, that $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i$ is non-prime for $N<20$, $\sum_{i=1}^{20} a_i = 71$, and that $71$ provides the maximum number over all primes.  I'm fairly sure I've never written that number before now in a mathematics problem!

Comment: As @fedja suggests, I computed the full table of probabilities of ending up at integer $i$ after $n$ rolls from $n \leq i \leq 6n$ and $n \leq 256$.  Going out to $n = 128$ took at most a second on my incredibly crappy laptop, going to out 256 took at most 5 seconds.

Comment: Your method can easily calculate $a_0$ to any arbitrary precision.  For some prime $p$, let $b_p$ and the next five values $b_{p+1}$ through $b_{p+5}$ equal $0$. Let $c_p=0$ and the next five values $c_{p+1}$ through $c_{p+5}$ equal some value $x$ that is sure to be greater than the actual value. Then $b_0<a_0<c_0$, and these bounds get tighter as the initial choice for $p$ increases.

Comment: @DanielMathias Note that $a_i$ is unbounded above, so your idea of "some value $x$ that is sure to be greater than the actual value" might be much harder to substantiate, as you don't know how much further you have to go backtrack to ensure the max. $\quad$ EG If we have 26 composite integers in a row (first occurrence is $c=189695660$), then the first $a_c$ value is $> 9$. This arises because $a_c$ is calculated as "1 plus average of next 6 values", so it keeps on increasing (if none of the values are set to 0). $\quad$ EG $a_{19} > 4.4$, which was surprising to me given the above writeup.

Comment: $a_{19}=0$, but $a{888}>10$ and your point is valid. I mean for $x$ to be much greater than any reasonable estimate.